# Cache some files, not the others

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, caching, browser-cache

I have page with static content (.jpg) mixed with server side cached content (.jpg too).

```
<body>

// Static content, "never change"
<img src="my_static_image.jpg">

// This image change every 6 hours, its name will not change.
<img src="changing_image.jpg">

<body>
```

I would like to optimize loading and refresing only the content that change, not the rest.
In my case, changing_image.jpg keep the same name but is re-generated every 6 hours on serveur side.

Comment: This answer if I want to cache all jpeg for 6 hours.
My problem is to cache some jpeg 6 hours, the others 15 days for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found on http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/speed-up-sites-with-htaccess-caching.html#Apache_htaccess_caching_code

```
<FilesMatch "/static/"> <-- this is regex, you can match by filename rather than by extention
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=29030400, public" <-- longer
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "/changing/"> <-- this is regex, you can match by filename rather than by extention
    Header set Cache-Control "max-age=21600, public" <--6 hours in seconds
</FilesMatch>
```

Comment: Yes, but what about my same type files (.jpg). Some must be cached 6 hours, the others (15 days for example).